# Using htaccess to make a public facing url with subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking to have a public facing url depending on the folder / page the user is on. Most ideal would be that the htaccess accepts the folder name and uses that as the subdomain. In a not so ideal bit of code the htaccess could simply be if user goes to X domain go to Y domain and have that ready for each page. I'm not too experienced with htaccess and I'm hoping I worded this question appropriately. Let me know if there needs to be more clarification.

Public facing URL: http://subdomain.domain.com

Actual URL: http://domain.com/folder/subdomain

Public facing URL: http://subdomain.domain.com/about

Actual URL: http://domain.com/folder/subdomain/about

Answer (score 1):

This .htaccess should work for you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) http://domain.com/folder/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The RewriteCond will match all subdomains of domain.com, case insensitive.

The RewriteRule will point that subdomain to domain.com/folder/{subdomain}/{request} and pass along any query string parameters that were there.

Test it out on http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: Thanks for the response Slapyo, I tried out the htaccess tester and got no luck. I don't know if this is just the tester. I inputed the domain as http://subdomain.domain.com then tried http://domain.com/folder/subdomain.